# Откуда None в выводе ? Глупый вопрос

Tags: python, ооп, python-3.5, print, методы

Вот собственно сам код программы :

```
import time

class TestClass(object):
    """docstring for ."""
    def __init__(self, name, yearofbirth, mounthofbith, dayofbith):
        super(TestClass, self).__init__()
        self.fname = name
        self.born = yearofbirth
        self.born1 = mounthofbith
        self.born2 = dayofbith
    def vozrast(self):
        self.year = int(time.strftime('%Y'))
        self.mounth= int(time.strftime('%m'))
        self.day = int(time.strftime('%d'))
        if (self.mounth >= self.born1):
            if(self.day >= self.born2):
                self.age = self.year - self.born

        else:
            self.age = int(self.year) - self.born - 1

        self.ret = self.age
        return self.ret
    def bio(self):
        self.old = self.vozrast()
        print(self.fname, self.old)



Ivan = TestClass('Ivan', 1999, 7, 2)
Sasha = TestClass('Sasha', 1976, 7 , 14)

print(Ivan.bio())
print(Sasha.bio())
```

Вывод:

```
('Ivan', 18)
None
('Sasha', 41)
None
[Finished in 0.027s]
```

Откуда "None" и как убрать ?

Comment: `print(Ivan.bio())` печатает то, что возвращает метод `bio`, а он у вас возвращает ничего, то есть `None`. А тот принт, который внутри метода `bio`, печатает вам ивана-18 и не имеет никакого отношения к возвращаемому значению

Comment: @andreymal, добавь ответ.

Comment: Добавьте кто-нибудь за меня, я считаю вопрос плохим и мне лень писать развёрнутый ответ

Comment: @user263096 Выякий метод и всякая функция в Пытоне возвращает какое-то значение: Или то, которое в команде `return`, или `None`, когда `return` не встретится.

Comment: @MarianD, зачем ты мне это объясняешь? Я - то не создатель этого дурацкого вопроса.

Comment: @user263096, ты писал "@andreymal, добавь ответ", и так я думал, что ты это хочешь. Извини.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def bio(self):
    self.old = self.vozrast()
    print(self.fname, self.old)
```

В этом методе нет команды `return`, и так она возвращает значение `None`.

Вы вероятно хотели

```
def bio(self):
    self.old = self.vozrast()
    return (self.fname, self.old)
```

или - более просто -

```
def bio(self):
    return self.fname, self.vozrast()
```